# Set Value to a dynamically created Ion-Input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a dynamically created Ion-Input control.

Below that there is a button on click on that button i will open the scanner and read the bar code. I want this bar code to appear on the Ion-Input that i created dynamically.

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
        [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

<button type="button" ion-button (click)="Scan"></button>

Scan(){
 return barcodeasString;
}
```

I want the barcode to appear on the ion-input. I tried to pass the this object and question object and set its value but it didnt work.

Any hints would be helpful!!

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZmzmANTP3bpFmSX7lle0?p=preview

Comment: So when the user clicks on the button, you want the input value to equal `barcodeasString` that `scan()` returned?

Comment: First you need to call the function: Should be (click)="Scan()". You could use ngModel and assign the value to the model in the scan function.

Comment: @BeetleJuice 
When the user clicks on the button. I want to show the scanner to scan the barcode then the detected barcode should go into that dynamic text field.

Comment: @Notmfb there wont be any ngModel as the model is also dynamic.

Comment: instead of returning barcode...store it in a variable and use {{variable}} with the ion-input

Comment: Do what ewizard said. I must be confused about what you're trying to do, because it seems like using ngModel would do exactly what you want... when the variable updates in the component (after receiving it through scanning) it would update the input field.

Comment: @Notmfb Can you show how to do it? I tried it didn't work. You can use the link below.


https://plnkr.co/edit/ZmzmANTP3bpFmSX7lle0

Comment: See my answer below. Worked in your plunkr

Comment: This approach will make the form static. I will have to use the dynamically created controlname in the TS file

Answer (score 1):

In your `app/dynamic-form-question.component.html` file, you can change it to either of these:

1. One-way Binding:

   `<input #scannerInput [ngModel]="question.value"
   [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" >`
2. Two-way Binding:

   `<input #scannerInput [(ngModel)]="question.value"
    [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" >`

Basically, one way binding will update the view when the controller updates the value. Two way binding does the same as one-way but also works in reverse (updates the controller when the view is updated.