# ion-input value not showing unless set in afterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an account management page. On this page there is an input for the user's email address. In the TypeScript file I try to set the value of the email based on the current user. When I set the value in the constructor, in `ngOnInit()`, or in `ngAfterContentInit()` the value doesn't show in the input. If you look in the dev tools, it will show the value in the `ng-reflect-value` property, but won't show in the input. The other two values (`emailVerified` and `verificationText`) both work how I expect them to, it is just the value for the input that isn't doing what I would expect.

HTML snippet

```html
<ion-item class="ion-margin-vertical" fill="solid">
    <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input [value]="userEmail" name="userEmail" type="email" ngModel email></ion-input>
    <ion-button slot="end" [color]="emailVerified" class="ion-padding-start ion-no-margin" (click)="verifyEmail()">
        <ion-icon name="shield-checkmark-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        {{ verificationText }}
    </ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

TypeScript snippet

```js
export class AccountSettingsComponent implements OnInit {
    emailVerified: 'success' | 'warning' | 'danger' = 'warning';
    verificationText: string = 'Verify';
    userEmail: string | null = '';
    user: User;

    constructor(authService: AuthService) {
        this.user = authService.getUserData()
        this.userEmail = this.user.email
        this.emailVerified = this.user.emailVerified ? 'success' : 'warning'
        this.verificationText = this.user.emailVerified ? 'Verified' : 'Verify'
    }

    ...
}
```

When I set the value in the `ngAfterViewInit()` it displays the value in the input, but I get an error saying that some value was changed after it was checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was creating this question, I came across this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334282/set-value-to-a-dynamically-created-ion-input), that doesn't directly answer this question, but it does contain a solution.

The one-way binding being used on the input is in the wrong place. Because you are using `ngModel` we need to add the one-way binding on that property (two-way binding will work as well, but only use it if that is what you need). Like this:

```html
<ion-item class="ion-margin-vertical" fill="solid">
    <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input name="userEmail" type="email" [ngModel]="userEmail" email></ion-input>
    <ion-button slot="end" [color]="emailVerified" class="ion-padding-start ion-no-margin" (click)="verifyEmail()">
        <ion-icon name="shield-checkmark-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        {{ verificationText }}
    </ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

This will set the starting value of the input using the `ngModel` property instead of the `value` property.